# asp.net  dynamic list box "error fetching data"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Thank you for everyone's help so far! Have had some really helpful answers on this site so far. So I am hoping for one more.

What I want to create is **exactly** this, but i'm still having problems.

http://www.webonweboff.com/widgets/ajax/ajax_linked_selection.aspx

I have copied the html and javascript word for word and saved that file as index.html (but obviously with open and close html and body tags)

The file I have called ajaxServer.aspx.cs has the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        string id = Request.QueryString.Get("id");
        string action = Request.QueryString.Get("action");
        StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();

        /* 
            Retrieve the data based on values "id" and "action"
            and build a response string in this format: 
                [{text:"...",
         * 
         * value:"...",selected:false},
                 {text...}]
            No final ";" is necessary

            For example:
        returnString.Append("[{text:\"California\",value:\"CA\",selected:false}," +
                             "{text:\"OH\",value:\"Ohio\",selected:false}," + 
                             "{text:\"NY\",value:\"New York\",selected:true}]");

        */

        Response.Write(returnString.ToString());
    }
}
```

and the file I have called ajaxServer.aspx has the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="ajaxServer.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

The other (.js) files I have downloaded and saved. When I run the .html file i get the following error:

error fetching data!

url:ajaxServer.asp

method:GET

params:action=state,culture=en-us

readyState:4

status:403

headers:Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Sun, 19 Jun 2011 20:39:55 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2126
Connection: Close

--> Any clues anyone? And once again - thank you for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is a typo in their example code.  ajaxServer.asp is refering to a classic asp page and not the ASPX page that you were asked to create.  You're essentially telling the page to GET from a non-existent page.

Try changing the following line in the Javascript:

**From this**

```
var stateCities = new ylib.widget.AjaxLinkedSelection(
                                "state", "city", 
                                "ajaxServer.asp", 
                                "GET", paramsCity);
```

**To this**

```
var stateCities = new ylib.widget.AjaxLinkedSelection(
                                "state", "city", 
                                "ajaxServer.aspx", 
                                "GET", paramsCity);
```

Look at the source of the page and you'll see that the actual Javascript is refering to the aspx page.  A check in Fiddler confirms that the aspx page is being requested and not the asp page.

Comment: Ah-Ha! So now my error has disappeared but I get my 2 boxes (like in the example) but my 2nd box is always blank... :(